# How to specify justification of contents in `amsmath`'s `align` environment?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, align, amsmath

Consider this MWE:

```
\documentclass[preview]{standalone}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
    \begin{align*}
        &\phantom{\rightarrow} & \text{2nd-order mechanics} \\
        &\rightarrow & \text{non-negligible inertia} \\
        &\rightarrow & \text{directional migration} 
    \end{align*}

    \begin{align*}
        &\phantom{\rightarrow} & \text{rule: decaying persistence memory} & \\
        &+ & \text{rule: increase persistence after collision} & \\
        &\rightarrow & \text{directional migration} &
    \end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

I would like the end result to look like:

```
    2nd-order mechanics 
--> non-negligible inertia 
--> directional migration 

    rule: decaying persistence memory  
 +  rule: increase persistence after collision  
--> directional migration
```

The two examples are slightly different, because in the second `environment`, I would like to make sure that the `\rightarrow`s and the `+` are visually centered in their environment (set justification to centered for that column)?

In both examples, I want the text itself to be left justified within its column.

How can I force this behaviour? Or am I using the wrong tool? I could use a table (for instance, see):

```
\documentclass[preview]{standalone}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tabular}{cl}
        $\phantom{\rightarrow}$ & 2nd-order mechanics \\ 
        $\rightarrow$ & non-negligible inertia \\
        $\rightarrow$ & directional migration  
    \end{tabular} 

    \begin{tabular}{cl}
        $\phantom{\rightarrow}$ & rule: decaying persistence memory \\ 
        $+$ & rule: decaying persistence memory \\
        $\rightarrow$ & directional migration  
    \end{tabular} 
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: First comment: The \phantom s doesn't offer something in the place it used in your code... but could offer on the centering part... Second: The symbol & is used to LEFT-align "columns" that following... You using it with a really strange way (with nothing before or after)... And because of this, it is not supposed to center any columns. So... Answer: yes! a table is a better option (since you not even have any math in there... But even if you had, this environment has really different usage)... What is your problem with the table

Comment: Yes, you should use a `tabular`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Like this?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
    \begin{align*}
         & \text{2nd-order mechanics} \\
    \to{}& \text{non-negligible inertia} \\
    \to{}& \text{directional migration} \\[2ex]
         & \text{rule: decaying persistence memory}\\
    {}+{}& \text{rule: increase persistence after collision} \\
    \to{}& \text{directional migration}
    \end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Observe that the code in this answer employs only one &-based alignment point in both the upper and lower group. (In contrast, your setup features two or even three & alignment points.) Note the presence of `{}` -- known as an "empty math group" -- in both `\to{}` and `{}+{}`. The empty math groups are crucial for obtaining horizontal spacing that's appropriate for relational operators, such as `\to` (aka `\rightarrow`), and binary operators such as `+`. (To verify this, run the answer *without* the empty math groups and see what happens.) Finally, why is it necessary to provide *two* empty math groups for `+` but only one for `\to` in order to get the correct spacing? The reason is buried deep down in the way the `amsmath` package chose to implement its alignment operations whenever it encounters an instance of `&`. (If you really want to know how LaTeX handles these alignment operations, in all gory detail, please ask a new question.)

---

Alternatively, consider employing an `array` environment.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{$}l<{$}}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{{}}c<{{}}}

\begin{document}
\[
\setlength\arraycolsep{0pt}
\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.33}
\begin{array}{CL}
         & 2nd-order mechanics \\
    \to  & non-negligible inertia \\
    \to  & directional migration \\[2ex]
         & rule: decaying persistence memory\\
    +    & rule: increase persistence after collision \\
    \to  & directional migration
\end{array}
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you explain why your first version using align works, but mine doesn't?

Comment: In the `align*`-based solution I provided, there's only one `&`-based alignment point, in both the upper and lower group. (In contrast, your setup features two or even three `&` alignment points.) Note the presence of `{}` in `\to{}`; that's crucial for obtaining spacing that's appropriate for relational operators (such as `\to`, aka `\rightarrow`).

Comment: Mico, could you update your answer with that explanation, and can you also write a bit more about  what`{}` is? e.g. can you explain why you do `{}+{}` but only `\to{}`?

Comment: @user89 - Done. :-)

Answer (score 3):

Here is a solution showing what was saying in my comment (in the first two align's) and creating an environment for this strange approach of align usage:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{environ}
\usepackage{amsmath}


\NewEnviron{strangealign}{\def\ra{\rightarrow\,\hspace{60pt}}\def\pl{+\,\,\hspace{60pt}}\begin{align*}\BODY\end{align*}}



\begin{document}
    \begin{align*}
        & \text{2nd-order mechanics} \\
        \rightarrow\hspace{10pt} & \text{non-negligible inertia} \\
        \rightarrow\hspace{10pt} & \text{directional migration} 
    \end{align*}

    \begin{align*}
        & \text{rule: decaying persistence memory}  \\
        +\,\,\hspace{40pt}& \text{rule: increase persistence after collision}  \\
        \rightarrow\,\hspace{40pt}& \text{directional migration} 
    \end{align*}

    \begin{strangealign}
      &\text{Initial text}\\
      \pl&\text{Some text here}\\
      \ra&\text{Some other text left aligned}
    \end{strangealign}
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

This is a job for `tabular`:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\tra}{\ensuremath{\rightarrow}}% text right arrow

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{@{}r@{ }l@{}}
     & 2nd-order mechanics \\
\tra & non-negligible inertia \\
\tra & directional migration
\end{tabular}

\qquad\vrule\qquad

\begin{tabular}{@{}r@{ }l@{}}
     & rule: decaying persistence memory \\
+    & rule: increase persistence after collision \\
\tra & directional migration
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

The vertical rule is just for separating the two tables.

[image]

This is what happens if I use `\begin{tabular}{@{}c@{ }l@{}}` in order to center the symbols in the first column.

[image]

Comment: @koleygr That's a stylistic decision.

Comment: @koleygr OK, added the output and the suggestion on how to get it.